# How is matter defined in physics?

Tags: terminology, definition, matter

I have heard matter defined as energy within a closed system and that any such closed system will have mass.

Is this correct?

Comment: Heard where? If a system was just a single photon it certainly doesn't have mass.

Comment: Are you thinking of $E = mc^2$?

Comment: probable dupe: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/478273/

Comment: @Gerry, you can use the search bar at the top of this web site to search to duplicate/similar questions before you post a new question.

Comment: That's not a very good definition. A closed system has to be surrounded by matter. There is no other way to keep it from losing energy to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think that there is one single definition of matter. Different specialties have different definitions.

In chemistry it is defined as something that has mass and takes up space.

In general relativity a matter field is anything with a non zero stress energy tensor.

In quantum field theory matter usually is a fermion field.

I am sure there are different definitions in other specialties. You should understand how a specific author is using the term in a given paper or book. I personally have never read anything that defined matter as “energy within a closed system” but an author has the prerogative to make definitions that they find useful (and the community has the prerogative to reject an author that makes definitions they find useless).

Comment: Thank you.  Kant, in the Metaphysics of Natural Science, gives a proof of the law of the conservation of matter which can be demonstrated by dissolving salt in water and confirming that the total mass of both the water and the salt are unchanged even though the salt is dissolved.  This proves that while particles can be combined and separated, they can never be destroyed.  This is part of a useful model for explaining the phenomena that Kant and scientists of this Newtonian era were trying to explain, and in that sense, is a correct explication of matter.

Comment: When the quantum physicist talks about matter, she is using the term differently to describe different phenomena.  Kant discusses the general experience of matter, the salt and water experiment considers matter from a chemistry perspective, and quantum physics from yet another. All three are correct relative to the phenomena they're analyzing. If I think of science as the development of explanatory models rather than providing the right, true answer, then much of my problems go away.